# Laravel - Map Eloquent collection using a value as key, pushing an array into the keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

I have a model that has a query, that returns the next eloquent collection.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4431
 all: [
   App\Models\ProductVariation {#4429
     attribute_value_id: 48,
     name: "Storlek",
     value: "Small",
   },
   App\Models\ProductVariation {#4438
     attribute_value_id: 41,
     name: "Storlek",
     value: "Medium",
   },
   App\Models\ProductVariation {#4439
     attribute_value_id: 34,
     name: "Storlek",
     value: "Large",
   },
   App\Models\ProductVariation {#4440
     attribute_value_id: 70,
     name: "Color",
     value: "Green",
   },
 ],
}
```

I need to map this collection into Array, keyed by "name"

```
[
  "Storlek" => [...]
  "Color" => [...]
]
```

I try with KeyBy, groupBy, and mapWithKeys, with those methods, it keeps only the last element into the array

The solution that I find is the next:

```
$map = [];

    foreach($variations as $value)
    {
        $key = $value["name"];
        if(!isset($map[$key]))
            $map[$key] = [];

        $map[$key][] = $value;
    }
    return $map;
```

Is that the only solution? is there any other best solution?

**EDIT:**

I use the ->toArray() method to iterate the collection

Comment: Just use groupBy collection's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `groupBy` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) method.

```php
$mapped = $variations->groupBy(function($item){
            return $item->name;
        });

dd($mapped->toArray());
```

This will return your data grouped by the name.

Also, if you only want to return the value (and not the whole ProductVariation), you could also remap the grouped Collection:

```
$mapped = $variations->groupBy(function($item){
            return $item->name;
        })->map(function($group){
            return $group->map(function($item){
                return $item->value;
            });
        });

dd($mapped->toArray());
```

Comment: I updated my answer since I think you want the entire ProductVariation as key, not only their value. As you can see it's a minor change.

Comment: This does not work. This only return one item in the array, only the last one

Comment: Sorry I indeed made a mistake. I updated the answer, it is fixed now.